# Prove Upper Bound (Big O) for Fibonacci's Sequence?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

NOTE: We are not to use proofs (limits, induction, or otherwise) in this problem.

We were to prove the upper bound for the Fibonacci recursion is some exponential. The Fibonacci recurrence relation is given as T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + 1. Can someone please explain the recursive substitution happening here:

```
Prove T(n) = O(α^n).
α^n = α^(n-1) + α^(n-2) + 1
α^2 = α + 1 + 1/(α^(n-1))
α^2 = α + 1
α = 1.618 (approx.)

T(n) is interchangeable.
O(n) = 1.6^n
```

And how is this proving the upper bound, Big O, for that recursion? We are supposed to prove that the upper bound for T(n)=T(n/2) + 1 is O(log n).

Comment: The recurrence is wrong, the +1 is spurious

Comment: You seem to have mixed up the question on the Fibonacci sequence with a question on divide-and-conquer algorithm.

Comment: It's pretty close to the Fibonacci recurrence (in fact the terms are just shifted by $1$), so you could say it's Fibonacci-like.

Answer (score 2):

Your $T(n)$ is not the Fibonacci sequence, but that doesn't matter; the asymptotic growth is still the same. Indeed, set $U(n) = T(n) + 1$, so that the recurrence relation becomes $$U(n) = U(n-1) + U(n-2).$$

Now suppose you want to prove that $T(n) = O(\alpha^n)$ (or equivalently, that $U(n) = O(\alpha^n)$) for some $\alpha$. This means that for all $n \ge 1$, $U(n) \le c \alpha^n$ for some constant $c$. (Usually one says "for all suffiicently large $n$", but you can make it "for all $n$" by picking a $c$ large enough.)

So, assuming that you have proved this for a couple of base cases (which you anyway have to do: you haven't specified $T(1)$ and $T(2)$ or any such starting points to determine the sequence), to prove it by induction you'd have to prove that
$$U(n) \le c \alpha^n$$
starting from the induction hypothesis that $U(m) \le c\alpha^m$ for all $m < n$.
So, you'd need
$$c \alpha^{n-1} + c\alpha^{n-2} \le c \alpha^n,$$
or dividing throughout by $c\alpha^{n-1}$,
$$ 1 + \alpha \le \alpha^2.$$

This is true, among $\alpha > 1$, for $\alpha = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ (or greater), and therefore you have proved that $T(n) = O(\alpha^n)$ for any such $\alpha$.

---

Without the $U(n) = T(n) + 1$ trick, we'd want to prove that
$$1 + \alpha + \frac{1}{c\alpha^{n-1}} \le \alpha^2$$
for some large $n$, which we can say (as $1/{c\alpha^{n-1}} \to 0$) is satisfied for $\alpha$ only slightly larger than the solution $1 + \alpha = \alpha^2$.

---

In general, given any linear recurrence relation, the same trick works: guess that the general $n$th term is of the form $cx^n$, write down an equation for $x$ (which will be a polynomial), and if $\alpha$ is the largest root of that polynomial equation, then you'll have $T(n) = O(\alpha^n)$.

Answer (score 0):

First, the Fibonacci recurrence is really $F_{n + 2} = F_{n + 1} + F_n$ with $F_0 = 0$, $F_1 = 1$.

If you compute a few $F_{n + 1} / F_n$, you'll see they seem to converge to a value near 1.6. As the question doesn't ask for the "best" $a$, we can as well pick $a = 2$ if that makes the work simpler. So we want to prove that there is a constant $c$ such that $F_n \le c \cdot 2^n$ for large enough $n$. It looks like $c = 1$ will do.

Certainly we have $F_0 \le 1 \cdot 2^0$ and $F_1 \le 1 \cdot 2^1$ as base cases. Now use induction:
$$
F_{n + 2} = F_{n + 1} + F_n
          \le 2^{n + 1} + 2^n
          \le 2^{n + 2}
$$
and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your response. While I understand using induction to solve this would be relatively simple, our assignment wants it done "without proofs" (done in the way as shown in the question). And I don't know what's being done in that example.

Comment: @user128400, the discussion you give would need a proof to wrap it up.

Answer (score -1):

in Fibonacci sequence, we know that

$$a_n={\frac { \left( \sqrt {5}+1 \right) ^{n}+ \left( 1-\sqrt {5} \right) ^
{n}}{{2}^{n}}}$$

now, $O(a_n) = O\left({\frac { \left( \sqrt {5}+1 \right) ^{n}}{{2}^{n}}} \right)$

$=O((1.62)^n)$ (Rounding off to 2 decimal places)

Infact you can write this as

$= O(2^n)$

Comment: I think you have your last $^n$ outside the brackets when you wanted it inside?

Comment: yes,, edited now, m a little beginner with LateX, i will improve soon :)

Comment: you're pretty good for a beginner. I'm still making those mistakes after years and years! You've probably seen this, but in case you haven't: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.